# Change the scroll behavior to make it scroll horizontally for a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add sections on my website that change the behavior of the scroll.
Initially, the section is not at the top of the page so the scroll has default behavior, the page will scroll vertically.

[image: Initial]

Once the section hits the top of the page, if the right part of the section is not visible, the scroll would change to make the content of the section scroll horizontally

[image: Horizontal scroll starts here]

[image: End of section reached]

Once the right end of the section has been reached, the default behavior of the scroll starts working as usual and the rest of the page may scroll normally.

[image: Scroll to the bottom]

I've been trying different things inspired by https://github.com/htdt/parallax or https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24988-horizontal-parallax-scrolling/ but I was unable to integrate them along with a normal vertical scrolling behavior.

I would like to make something generic,in particular which would work with multiple horizontal scrolling section within a single page.

Is there any library that implements this kind of behavior, or how should I proceed if I want to implement such a thing ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this where you calculate the window height / width and then transform the div on scroll like you said

```js
const spaceHolder = document.querySelector('.space-holder');
const horizontal = document.querySelector('.horizontal');
spaceHolder.style.height = `${calcDynamicHeight(horizontal)}px`;

function calcDynamicHeight(ref) {
  const vw = window.innerWidth;
  const vh = window.innerHeight;
  const objectWidth = ref.scrollWidth;
  return objectWidth - vw + vh + 300; // 144 is the padding (in pixels) desired on the right side of the .cards container. This can be set to whatever your styles dictate
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
  horizontal.style.transform = `translateX(-${sticky.offsetTop}px)`;
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  spaceHolder.style.height = `${calcDynamicHeight(horizontal)}px`;
});


const reavealer = document.querySelectorAll('.revealer');

revealerObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
        for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            if (entries[i].intersectionRatio > 0) { // This should be a value between 0 and 1
                // 0 means the element is starting to appear in the viewport.
                // 1 means the element is 100% in the viewport.
                entries[i].target.classList.add('show-revealer');
            } else {
                entries[i].target.classList.remove('show-revealer');
            }
        }
    });
    if (reavealer.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < reavealer.length; i++) {
            revealerObserver.observe(reavealer[i]);
        }
    }
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.outer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10rem 4rem;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.space-holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  will-change: transform;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.sample-card {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.revealer {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s opacity ease-in-out, .2s transform ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(.5);
}

.show-revealer {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h1>Scroll down to see the effect</h1>
</div>

<section class="container">
  <div class="space-holder">
    <div class="sticky">
      <div class="horizontal">
        <section role="feed" class="cards">
          <article class="sample-card revealer"></article>
          <article class="sample-card revealer"></article>
          <article class="sample-card revealer"></article>
          <article class="sample-card revealer"></article>
          <article class="sample-card revealer"></article>
          <article class="sample-card revealer"></article>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="outer">
  <h1>Scroll up to see it again</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is neat. However I can not have several space-holders/horizontal sections since you select all matching divs by class. I would like to make it more generic so that I could have as many horizontal scrolling section on the page as I want. But I'm not sure how I should change your code to the desired behavior ... I think I need to select only the topmost fully visible horizontal section and make it only this one scrollable, but it seems quite difficult to do so ...